# FrameLayout onClick event is not triggering even clickable attribute is true

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-framelayout

I am trying to show a loading view, it contains a ProgressBar. When I clicked on the FrameLayout, FrameLayout's onClickListener method is not triggering. I can click anything behind the FrameLayout. In many topics, clickable attribute is recommending but it didn't work for me. Am I missing anything? I cropped the main code parts due to length, here it is.

What did I try?

- Set clickable attribute to true on XML and setOnClickListener for FrameLayout.

loading_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flLoadingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:clickable="true"**
    android:alpha="0.4"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/loadingView"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbCalculate"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        **android:clickable="false"**
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:minHeight="25dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/colMain"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clSuperMainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/layoutBackground">

        **<include layout="@layout/layout_loading"/>**

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId=""
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clFormView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clSubMainLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity">

                    <!-- Guide Lines -->

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilMainAmount"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/main_amount"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/glStart"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/glEnd"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glHorizontal">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:maxLength="12"/>

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <!-- Other text input layouts. -->

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/mbtnCalculate"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/calculate"
                        android:textColor="@color/buttonStroke"
                        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/glEnd"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/glVertical"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llPeriod"
                        app:rippleColor="@color/buttonStroke"
                        app:strokeColor="@color/buttonStroke" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var tilMainAmount: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var mbtnCalculate: MaterialButton

    private lateinit var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout
    private lateinit var clSuperLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var clFormView: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var flLoadingView: FrameLayout

    private var inAnimation = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
    private var outAnimation = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    private var isValid = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.colMain)

        tilMainAmount = findViewById(R.id.tilMainAmount)
        
        clSuperLayout = findViewById(R.id.clSuperMainLayout)
        clFormView = findViewById(R.id.clFormView)
        flLoadingView = findViewById(R.id.flLoadingView)

        inAnimation.duration = 200
        outAnimation.duration = 200

        mbtnCalculate.setOnClickListener {
            uiScope.launch {
                flLoadingView.animation = inAnimation
                flLoadingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                isValid = checkInputs()
                if (isValid) {
                    calculate()
                }
                //flLoadingView.animation = outAnimation
                //flLoadingView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        flLoadingView.setOnClickListener {
            **println("Loading frame layout clicked.")** //I checked in debug mode, this line is not triggering.
        }

    }

    private fun checkInputs(): Boolean {
        ...
    }

    private suspend fun calculate() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using this layout inside another layout, so try to make its parent layout clickable to make layouts dispatch the click event.

Comment: I tried combinations for both (ConstraintLayout → id = clSuperMainLayout and CoordinatorLayout → id = colMain). It is still same.

Comment: Did you try setting `focusable` to true on the FrameLayout, in addition to `clickable`?